# Why can I not create an application on my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

I have created a Facebook "page" for a client, for the purposes of promoting their business. Forgive me but I'm not totally clear on the myriad of options and account types on Facebook, so I am not sure what the name for this type of Facebook account is. What I can say is that it only has a "page", and no personal information tied to any individual.

I want to create an application for this "page", where posts can come from an external web site. I have gone through this process before with other regular Facebook accounts. So I think I know how to do it, but I am unable to proceed, because this type of Facebook account is behaving differently than what I have seen before.

When I log in to Facebook, I see this home screen:

[image]

... I click on the bottom of the screen where it says "Developers":

[image]

... then on the following screen, I go to "Build Apps on Facebook":

[image]

The next screen offers me a link to the "Getting Started Guide Tutorial":

[image]

That's where I finally get to a link that says I can get started by creating an application:

[image]

***But***, I click it, and guess what? I'm taken back to the start:

[image]

So, what am I supposed to do to get out of this loop?

Comment: As I understand it, you can't create an App if you are logged in as `XYZ Page`. You have to log in using a User account. Only User Accounts can create Apps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be possible to reach the Developer App by going to https://developers.facebook.com/apps or https://facebook.com/developer.

If this does not work, first ensure that you are logged in to your personal Facebook account.  Facebook does not allow creation of apps from a business account.  Once you create the app you will be able to add other people as app administrators, developers, or testers.  It is also possible to convert the business account to a personal account if you don't already have one.  Note that a Facebook business account is not a Facebook account for a business; it is an account for an individual that is restricted to only certain business activities.

> [**What is the difference between a business account and a personal account?**](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=131976240210052)
>
> Business accounts are designed for individuals who only want to use the site to administer Pages and their ad campaigns. For this reason, business accounts do not have the same functionality as personal accounts. Business accounts have limited access to information on the site. An individual with a business account can view all the Pages and Social Ads that they have created, however they will not be able to view the profiles (timelines) of users on the site or other content on the site that does not live on the Pages they administer.  In addition, **business accounts cannot** be found in search, send or receive friend requests, or **create/develop apps**.

Next, ensure that you have verified your account with a [mobile phone](https://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php) or [credit card](https://secure.facebook.com/settings?tab=payments&section=methods&t).  If your account is not verified, or you have only verified your account using another method, then you may not be permitted to add any new apps.

> [**How do I verify my developer account?**](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=167551763306531)
>
> Facebook has several features in place to limit the potential for spam and abuse on the site. Verifying your Facebook account helps you retain control of your account and apps on Facebook. There are two ways to verify your account. First, you can verify your cell phone, which allows us to verify that a real person is in control of the account. This process is explained [here](https://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php).
>
> The second way to verify your account is to add a credit card to your account. You may do so [here](https://secure.facebook.com/cards.php).
>
> Unfortunately, if you cannot verify with a cell phone or add a credit card, you may be unable to verify your account. All developers must be verified before they can create a new app.

Also verify that you have not turned off Facebook Platform on your account.  From Privacy Settings go to Apps, Games, and Websites.  If you are using any third party apps or have the option to turn off all apps then Platform is enabled.  You might also verify that you have not blocked the Developer app: from Privacy Settings go to Manage Blocking and look under Blocked apps.

You can also check the [Developer app profile page](https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=2345053339) which should list some options on the left.  If it thinks that you have already added the app then there should be a Remove App link.

---

**Update:**
It sounds like you may be attempting to use a second account which was created as a business account.  According to [How do I create a business account?](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=228275060521343) *"managing multiple accounts is a serious violation of Facebook’s Terms of Use. If we determine that an individual has more than one account, we reserve the right to terminate all of their accounts."*  (Although oddly, I could not find that in the actual [Terms of Use](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms), which prohibits multiple personal profiles but doesn't seem to say anything about multiple accounts.)

If Facebook did allow two accounts, your second account would have to be another personal account if you wanted to use it to develop an app (a clear violation of Facebook terms, since a personal account always includes a personal profile).  Technically, I suspect that it has to be a personal account so that it it will have a profile to use for issuing access tokens, which are needed to use apps (such as the Developer app, and your own app that you are developing).  So to avoid violating the terms you will need to use your existing personal account to develop an app.  Although a personal account is required to develop an app, a page can be administered using a business account if there is no need to use the app with that account.

Note that a business page and business account are not the same; you may create as many business pages as you like using a single account (login/password).  Unless you set yourself as a "Featured Page Owner", the page will not link back to your profile, and your profile will not link to the page if you don't "like" or share it.  As a page admin you can also post and comment as the page, even though you are logged in to your personal account, and these posts and comments will link to the page and will not appear on your personal profile or in the News Feed of your friends (unless they "like" the page).  So most people will see no association between the page and your personal profile.  Only other page admins will be able to see you in the list of page admins.  You can add as many other admins as you want, and after adding other admins you can remove yourself as a page admin if you want to completely sever all ties between you and the page.

Comment: @Dave: I understand your concern.  I've updated my answer with more information on this.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option, you can create an app using your personal account, and just assign it to your business page. I had the same problem, it took me awhile to figure out how it can be done. 
You cannot create an app using the business page. Only your personal account. 
Best regards

Comment: This worked for me. I did the Facebook App creation steps on my personal account after failing with the business page's account. Then I continued the steps (for my Wordpress plugin that auto-posts to FB) and didn't really have to do anything special besides using the App ID and secret that come from FB.

Answer (score 1):

You need to request permission from the [Developer App](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) or for more information see the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/)