# Creating Facebook business page with my design and my buttons

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I'm new to Facebook. I was asked to design and create a business page for the customer. He has a business FB account.

I've tried to create a page, upload an image on it (although it was cut to 851px x 315px). Seems like that's not what I'm actually need. So, I'm stuck. I've read [Why can I not create an application on my Facebook page?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23082/why-can-i-not-create-an-application-on-my-facebook-page) , but I'm still curious if I really need to choose an App on Facebook from https://developers.facebook.com/apps application or I have to do it in another way.

I want my image on FB to be about 800px to 800px and have some text, my own buttons above the image that link to the business page etc.

I think I need something like [this company](http://www.facebook.com/BMW/app_441731479172531) has on FB (just an example).
But, I don't know from what link at Facebook I should start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The facebook page you linked to is not actually a page but a facebook application, an facebook application can have custom html, dynamic pages and other stuff, an *actual* facebook page can have an cover photo and profile pic only.

You cannot customize a facebook page so you can write an facebook application, facebook's guide to creat a application can be found below.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/
- http://www.labnol.org/internet/create-custom-facebook-pages/17957/