# How to assign an Facebook app created by personal account to a business page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have the same problem as described here: 
[Why can I not create an application on my Facebook page?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23082/why-can-i-not-create-an-application-on-my-facebook-page)

At the end, there is a solution posted by Kate.  I do not know how to implement it. How can I assign a Facebook app created by a personal account to a business page? Does the personal account and the business page have to have the same owner? Can I create an app for my client using my personal account and then assign this app to my client's business page?

> There is an option, you can create an app using your personal account,
>   and just assign it to your business page. I had the same problem, it
>   took me awhile to figure out how it can be done. You cannot create an
>   app using the business page. Only your personal account. Best regards

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26479/migrating-facebook-app-from-a-personal-account-to-a-corporate-account.